# how to deal with type in java bounded wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I've following question:
Is it possible to do something like that:

```
class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
        fruits.add(apple);
        fruits.add(orange);

        List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();
        copyToSubType(fruits, apples, Apple.class);
    }

    private <T> void copyToSubType(List<T> source, List<? extends T> target, Class cls) {
        for (T element : source) {
            if (element.getClass() == cls) {
                target.add(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find some kind of general method that allows me to copy elements from concrete type to the list that contains only such types. 
I was thinking if it is possible to use the wildcards... but it seems that my approach isn't correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. But your method will vary with both the type of the source list, and the subtype that you want to detect. So you'll need it to have type parameters for them both.

Something like this:

```
private <T,S extends T> void copyToSubType(List<T> source, List<S> target, Class<S> cls) {
    for (T element : source) {
        if (cls.isInstance(element)) {
            target.add((S) element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok it works but with '==' instead of isInstance, but the compiler gives me unchecked warning... Now I wonder if it is possible to avoid the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Comment: I don't know of a way to get rid of the unchecked warning.  Just a note - I recommend using `isInstance` instead of `==` and `getClass()` in case you have a further subclass; for example, `Gravenstein extends Apple` - if you want a list of the `Apple`s, you probably want to include any `Gravenstein`s.  Using `isInstance` will include them - using `==` and `getClass()` will exclude them.

Comment: @kocko - Did you seriously change the number of spaces at the end of each sentence?

Comment: No, I wanted to remove my downvote but the system said that my downvote will be blocked unless the answer is edited. :)

Comment: @David Wallace that's useful, thanks. I've made inversion between cls and element, that's the reason of not working...

Comment: why write `isInstance` when it could be just `instanceof`

Comment: @Zhuinden - that was my first thought, but as kocko pointed out, it doesn't compile with `instanceof`.  You need the actual name of a class to use `instanceof`, not a variable of type `Class`.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. This is a really smart solution then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
if (element.getClass().isAssignableFrom(cls) {
    target.add((S) element);
}
```